# Complex GroupBy in C# LINQ lambda expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

Probably easy for long-time LINQ lambda expressions users, but I'm simply hitting the wall here...

I'm trying to get all Area objects that a user with certain ID can access. I'm using entity framework, if it matters for any reason.

```
context.AspNetUserRoles
    .Where(u => u.UserId == _currentUserId)
    .Select(ur => ur.AspNetRoles.RolePagePermissions.Select(pp => pp.Page.Area))
    .GroupBy(a => a.Select(g => g.Page.Select(gg => gg.Area)))
    .ToList()
```

Instead of getting a `List<Area>`, I'm getting `List<IGrouping<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Area>>>`

Anyone having any clues about how to do this easily?

As many pages can be in the same area, and roles are connected to pages, the following code returns many duplicate areas (as one user has access to many pages, therefore one area for each page is returned):

```
context.AspNetUserRoles.Where(u => u.UserId == _currentUserId).SelectMany(ur => ur.AspNetRoles.RolePagePermissions.Select(pp => pp.Page.Area)).ToList()
```

Here is the model for testing:

```
public partial class Area
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Area()
    {
        this.Page = new HashSet<Page>();
    }

    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public int CreationUser { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public byte Activated { get; set; }
    public string SimpleLineIcon { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Page { get; set; }
}

public partial class AspNetRoles
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public AspNetRoles()
    {
        this.AspNetUserRoles = new HashSet<AspNetUserRoles>();
        this.RolePagePermissions = new HashSet<RolePagePermissions>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<RolePagePermissions> RolePagePermissions { get; set; }
}

public partial class AspNetUserRoles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetRoles AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUsers AspNetUsers { get; set; }
}

public partial class AspNetUsers
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public AspNetUsers()
    {
        this.AspNetUserClaims = new HashSet<AspNetUserClaims>();
        this.AspNetUserLogins = new HashSet<AspNetUserLogins>();
        this.AspNetUserRoles = new HashSet<AspNetUserRoles>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
    public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
}

public partial class Page
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Page()
    {
        this.RolePagePermissions = new HashSet<RolePagePermissions>();
    }

    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public int CreationUser { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public byte Activated { get; set; }
    public int AreaId { get; set; }
    public string SimpleLineIcon { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }

    public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<RolePagePermissions> RolePagePermissions { get; set; }
}

public partial class RolePagePermissions
{
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public int CreationUser { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public byte AccessAllowed { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> AccessAllowedByDate { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetRoles AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual Page Page { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `context.AspNetUserRoles.Where(u => u.UserId == _currentUserId).Select(ur => ur.AspNetRoles.RolePagePermissions.Select(pp => pp.Page.Area)).GroupBy(a => a.SelectMany(g => g.Page.Select(gg => gg.Area))).ToList()`

Comment: in first select use `SelectMany`.

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh Got List<IGrouping<IEnumerable<Area>>>, so one IEnumerable less. Any ides how to get only List<Area>?

Comment: can you add your model in you question ? i want test it.

Comment: Added model in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one of the solutions that returns a list of all accessible areas:

```
context.AspNetUserRoles.Where(u => u.UserId == _currentUserId).SelectMany(ur => ur.AspNetRoles.RolePagePermissions.Select(pp => pp.Page.Area)).Distinct().ToList()
```

So .Distinct() made it all happen, thanks all for help.

Answer (score 0):

In LinqToEntities the `Select` method will return an `IQueryable` of the type that your are *selecting* in your expression (It is the same idea with LinqToObjects, but there you have `Function` instead of `Expression` as the parameter of your `Select` method, and it will return an `IEnumerable`).

So if you select a property that is of type `string`, you'll have an `IQueryable<string>`, in your case you're selecting a list inside another list. What you need to do in there is to use the `SelectMany` that just *unwraps* the returned collection from your `Expression` giving you only a single collection with all the items you would have.

You'll end up with something like this:

```
List<Area> userAreas = context.AspNetUserRoles.Where(u => u.UserId == _currentUserId)
    .SelectMany(ur => ur.AspNetRoles.RolePagePermissions.Select(pp => pp.Page.Area)).ToList();
```

Since you already know the id of the user and there is a relationship in your entity models between the user and their areas, it's not necessary to user a `GroupBy`.

Comment: This was the very first approach I tried before, but I end up getting this error: http://prntscr.com/ivuq8e any ideas why?

Comment: The second `SelectMany` should be a `Select`, `Area` isn't a collection

Comment: Thank you @Camilo Terevinto I've fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want:

```
    context.AspNetUserRoles.Where(u => u.UserId == _currentUserId)
   .SelectMany(ur => ur.AspNetRoles.RolePagePermissions.Select(pp => pp.Page.Area));
```

Not sure what you want to accomplish with the group by, but this will give the list of areas.

Comment: Sorry, removed the group by.  What did you want to group it by?

Comment: Many pages can belong to the same area, so my previous code returned many same areas out, so I wanted to group by area. Distinct helped here and solved the issue for now.